# Why wont jQueryUI buttons and javascript work when I'm using will_paginate?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, will-paginate

In my app I'm filtering through venue records using javascript and displaying them in partials on the venue index page. However, the filter form breaks when I have will_paginate set up, they both work individually but not together. What am I doing wrong here?

**jQuery script**

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".venuetypes").buttonset();
  });

  $(function() {
    $(".areas").buttonset();
  });

  $(function() {
    $( "button, input:submit, a", ".filter_form_button" ).button();
    $( "a", ".form_filter_button" ).click(function() { return false; });
  });
</script>
```

**filter form**

```
<div class="filter_options_container">
  <%= form_tag '', :method => :get, :id => 'filter_form' do %>

    <fieldset class="filter_form_fieldset venuetypes">
      <% Venuetype.all.each do |v| %>
        <p class="venuetype_check"><%= check_box_tag 'venuetypes[]', v.id, false, :id => "venuetype-#{v.id}" %>
        <label for="venuetype-<%= v.id %>"><%= v.name %></label></p>
      <% end %>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="filter_form_fieldset areas">
      <% Area.all.each do |a| %>
        <p class="area_check"><%= check_box_tag 'areas[]', a.id, false, :id => "area-#{a.id}" %>
        <label for="area-<%= a.id %>"><p1><%= a.name %></p1></label></p>
      <% end %>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="filter_form_button">
      <p2><input type="submit" value="Filter"/></p2>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**venue controller**

```
  def index
    if
      @venues = Venue.with_type(params[:venuetypes]).with_area(params[:areas]).order("average_rating DESC").all
    else
      @venues = Venue.all
    end
    @venues = Venue.paginate :all, :page => params[:page], :per_page => 15
  end
```

Thanks very much for any help its much appreciated!

Comment: make sure you see my updated code. You added a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the @venues variable, when I think you are trying to add pagination to that query. Try this instead:

```
def index
  if
    @venues = Venue.with_type(params[:venuetypes]).with_area(params[:areas]).order("average_rating DESC").all
  else
    @venues = Venue.all
  end
  @venues = @venues.paginate :per_page => 15, :page => params[:page]
end
```

Comment: @Dave no problem, it makes sense if you think about @venues representing a 'not yet executed' query. Each of the method calls creates a new query object rather than actually executing the query, otherwise you would end up doing all that filtering and sorting on the webserver not the database.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding an extra comma.

This is how it should be:

```
Model.pagination :per_page => 15, :page => params[:page]
```

So you should have this:

```
def index
  if
    @venues = Venue.with_type(params[:venuetypes]).with_area(params[:areas]).order("average_rating DESC").all
  else
    @venues = Venue.all
  end
  @venues = Venue.paginate :per_page => 15, :page => params[:page]
end
```

Comment: thanks for the answer it didn't change anything though, however If I change the controller to read: @venues = Venue.with_type(params[:venuetypes]).with_area(params[:areas]).order("average_rating DESC").all.paginate and remove the last line of code between the 2 'ends' It works, but I cant add the :per_page => 15 bit as it gives a syntax error.